# Can you play training modes offline in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

I would like to practice my skills in Overwatch. Do you have to be online in order to play in training mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you need to connect to the servers to authenticate. Launching Overwatch without an internet connection just repeatedly fails to connect to Battle.net.

Comment: But do the bots run locally or on overwatch servers?

Comment: This answer should be updated now that Overwatch has officially launched. The sentence "there aren't any servers online to connect to" hasn't been true for nearly a year now.